# Type map from System.Type to xs:type

Tags: .net, clr, xsd

Is there a standard (framework) mapping between CLR types and xsd type codes.
I need to convert a string, int, decimal etc to the equivalent XmlSchemaSimpleType.

I can construct the necessary simple type and use a case statement to do the mappings myself. I was hoping their might be a standard framework class that can either construct XmlSchemaSimpleType from the various CLR types, or perhaps even a mapping to XmlTypeCode from the CLR type.

System.String -> XmlTypeCode.String (for instance)

Thanks

UPDATE (07-07-2010)
Thanks, I have read the link it needed a little tweaking - for anyone else, here is the final code that can be pasted into linqpad.

```
public class XmlValueWrapper
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public static class XsdConvert
{
    private static XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlValueWrapper));


    public static object ConvertFrom(string value, string xsdType)
    {
        XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("XmlValueWrapper",
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xs", xsd),
                    new XElement("Value", 
                        new XAttribute(xsi + "type", xsdType),
                        new XText(value))
            )
        );
        doc.Dump("try");

        using (var reader = doc.CreateReader()) {
            XmlValueWrapper wrapper = (XmlValueWrapper) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            wrapper.Dump("ITEM");
            return wrapper.Value;
        }
    }

}
    public static void Main()
    {
        object o = XsdConvert.ConvertFrom("2010-01-02", "xs:date");
        o.GetType().Dump("object");
        /*
        Debug.Assert(Equals(42, XsdConverta.ConvertFrom("42", "xsd:int")));
        Debug.Assert(Equals(42.0, XsdConverta.ConvertFrom("42", "xsd:double")));
        Debug.Assert(Equals(42m, XsdConverta.ConvertFrom("42", "xsd:decimal")));
        Debug.Assert(Equals("42", XsdConverta.ConvertFrom("42", "xsd:string")));
        Debug.Assert(Equals(true, XsdConverta.ConvertFrom("true", "xsd:boolean")));
        Debug.Assert(Equals(new DateTime(2009, 4, 17), XsdConverta.ConvertFrom("2009-04-17", "xsd:date")));*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a central list of these, particularly since you can extend the `xs:type` declarations with your own types.

However, I did come up with this way to take advantage of the XML serializer's type mapping ability: http://www.partario.com/blog/2009/04/making-sense-of-xsd-type-names-in-c.html